# Клонирование двухмерного массива

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать клон двухмерного массива, чтобы можно было в клоне менять значения так, чтобы они не менялись при этом в исходном. Как это сделать?

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
let arr2 = Object.assign([], arr);
    
arr2[0][0] = 22;
    
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уже почти всё сделали

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
let arr2 = arr.map(el => Object.assign([],el));

arr2[0][0] = 22;

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

[Вот еще несколько вариантов, как это сделать](https://jsperf.com/clonearrayrace):

### JSON

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
arr2[0][0] = 22;
console.log(arr2[0][0], arr[0][0]);
```

### Concat

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
let arr2 = arr.map(el => [].concat(el));
arr2[0][0] = 22;

console.log(arr2[0][0], arr[0][0]);
```

### Slice

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
let arr2 = arr.map(el => el.slice(0));
arr2[0][0] = 22;

console.log(arr2[0][0], arr[0][0]);
```

### Если надо быстро

```js
arr2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  arr2[i]=[];
  for(var j = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
    arr2[i]=arr[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Ааа , для каждого внутреннего массива тоже нужен assign. Полезно

Comment: первый assign не нужен, map и так возвращает новый массив

Comment: А еще можно прогонять через json..

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko Зачем такие сложности? Проще тогда уж через csv)

Comment: @Darth, через csv вложенные не получатся

Comment: @Grundy вложенный csv с разными разделителями, не?

Comment: @Darth, а ты его вручную что ли собрался делать? :-) для json-то встроенные средства есть :)